# pybuilder and pytest: cannot import source code when running tests

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, pybuilder

so i have a project:

```
<root>
|- src
     |-main
         |-python
            |-data_merger
                |- common
                |- constans
                |- controller
                |- resources
                |- rest
     |-tests
         |-unittest
         |-integrationtest
```

data_merger is marked as root (I am using Pycharm).
This is part of my build file:

```
@init

def set_properties(project):
    project.set_property("dir_source_main_python", r"src\main\python\data_merger")
    project.set_property("dir_source_integrationtest_python", r"src\tests\integrationtest")
    project.set_property("dir_source_unittest_python", r"src\tests\unittest")
    project.set_property("unittest_module_glob", "*_test.py")
    project.set_property("unittest_test_method_prefix", "test_")
    project.set_property("run_unit_tests_command",
    "py.test %s" % project.expand_path("$dir_source_unittest_python"))
    project.set_property("run_unit_tests_propagate_stdout", True)
    project.set_property("run_unit_tests_propagate_stderr", True)
    project.set_property("teamcity_output", True)
```

when I build my project i get the following error that it cannot import my source code:

```
 ←[1m[INFO] ←[0;0m  ERROR collecting src/tests/unittest/python/data_merger/controller/comparator_autom_params_test.py
←[1m[INFO] ←[0;0m src\tests\unittest\python\data_merger\controller\comparator_autom_params_test.py:6: in <module>
←[1m[INFO] ←[0;0m     from resources.diff_table import DiffTable
←[1m[INFO] ←[0;0m E   ImportError: No module named resources.diff_table
```

Comment: There is no `resources` module or folder depicted in your diagram.

Comment: you're right, my diagram was wrong. I correct it now

Comment: I think you may need to use `from data_merger.resources.diff_table import DiffTable` assuming all these folders have an `__init__.py` in them.

Comment: the folder data_merger is marked as root. If i run my tests file per file, they run fine. It's only when i run them via pybuilder that it cannot seem to locate them

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/pybuilder/pybuilder/issues/13.

I ended up using [pytest-pythonpath](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-pythonpath). Here is the relevant part of my `build.py` :

```
from pybuilder.core import init, use_plugin

use_plugin("exec")
use_plugin("python.core")
use_plugin("python.unittest")

@init
def initialize(project):
    project.set_property("run_unit_tests_command", "py.test %s" % project.expand_path("$dir_source_unittest_python"))
    project.set_property("run_unit_tests_propagate_stdout", True)
    project.set_property("run_unit_tests_propagate_stderr", True)
```

And here is my `pytest.ini` :

```
[pytest]
python_paths = src/main/python
```

And now it works perfectly:

```
$ pyb run_unit_tests
```