# pytest cannot find module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am following the [pytest good practices](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/goodpractices.html#test-discovery) or at least I *think I am*. However, pytest cannot find my module. It seems not to include the current directory in its `PYTHONPATH`.

The source file:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

The test file:

```
import pytest
from junk.ook import add


def test_add_true():
    assert add(1, 1) == 2
```

And the shell output with a Python 3 virtual environment called "p3".

```
p3; pwd          
/home/usr/tmp/junk
p3; ls           
total 0
0 junk/  0 tests/
p3; ls junk      
total 4.0K
4.0K ook.py     0 __init__.py
p3; ls tests 
total 4.0K
4.0K test_ook.py     0 __pycache__/
p3; pytest
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.5, pytest-3.4.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /home/usr/tmp/junk, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors                                                   

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
______________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_ook.py ______________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/usr/tmp/junk/tests/test_ook.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_ook.py:2: in <module>
    from junk.ook import add
E   ImportError: No module named 'junk'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.08 seconds ============================
    
    def test_add_true():
        assert add(1, 1) == 2
```

However, running the following does work fine.

```
p3; python -m pytest tests/
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.5, pytest-3.4.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /home/usr/tmp/junk, inifile:
collected 1 item                                                               

tests/test_ook.py .                                                      [100%]

=========================== 1 passed in 0.02 seconds ===========================
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you add `__init__.py` to the tests folder also, does it help?

Comment: Adding a `__init__.py` in the tests directory did help. [But now this introduces a subtle problem…](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#test-discovery). It **should** work without an `__init__.py` file.

Comment: What problem does it introduce? The article you linked puts `__init__.py` in the `tests` directory and all directories (that include tests) inside it recursively.

Comment: But now this introduces a subtle problem: in order to load the test modules from the tests directory, pytest prepends the root of the repository to sys.path, which adds the side-effect that now mypkg is also importable. This is problematic if you are using a tool like tox to test your package in a virtual environment, because you want to test the installed version of your package, not the local code from the repository.

Comment: You have to install your package into your virtualenv. At least that's how I get rid of this error every time.

Comment: I hit the same error with PyCharm.  My error was self-inflicted.  I had forgotten to run `poetry add pytest --group dev`.  After that my tests came to life.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

#### Update for pytest 7 and newer: use the `pythonpath` setting

Recently, `pytest` has added a new core plugin that supports `sys.path` modifications via the [`pythonpath` configuration value](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-pythonpath). The solution is thus much simpler now and doesn't require any workarounds anymore:

`pyproject.toml` example:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = [
  "."
]
```

`pytest.ini` example:

```
[pytest]
pythonpath = .
```

The path entries are calculated relative to the rootdir, thus `.` adds `junk` directory to `sys.path` in this case.

Multiple path entries are also allowed: for a layout

```
junk/
├── src/
|   └── lib.py
├── junk/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── ook.py
└── tests
     ├── test_app.py
     └── test_lib.py
```

the configuration

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = [
  ".", "src",
]
```

or

```
[pytest]
pythonpath = . src
```

will add both `lib` module and `junk` package to `sys.path`, so

```
import junk
import lib
```

will both work.

#### Original answer

Just put an empty `conftest.py` file in the project root directory:

```
$ pwd
/home/usr/tmp/junk
$ touch conftest.py
```

Your project structure should become:

```
junk
├── conftest.py
├── junk
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── ook.py
└── tests
    └── test_ook.py
```

What happens here: when `pytest` discovers a `conftest.py`, it modifies `sys.path` so it can import stuff from the conftest module. So, since now an empty `conftest.py` is found in rootdir, `pytest` will be forced to append it to `sys.path`. The side effect of this is that your `junk` module becomes importable.

Comment: Your issue is that you have added an empty `contest.py`. It should be named `conftest.py`. I also had a typo in my answer, fixed that.

Comment: No worries! Btw check the answer in the linked question, the suggestion to install the package in editable mode is probably a more viable solution than abusing `pytest` test discovery mechanism.

Comment: Yes it sure is. And if I could make this a python package, I would. However, there are issue doing that in that ancient code base…

Comment: I've tried this solution and it doesn't seem to be working anymore... Python 3.7, pytest version 6.2.1. However running `python3.7 -m pytest` instead of just `pytest` works

Comment: @Expanding-Dev adding `conftest.py` continues to work with 6.2.1, you must have another issue with your project layout. If you want, ask a separate question with a [mcve] provided and ping me in the comments here.

Comment: Thanks! Adding `conftest.py` works with pytest 6.2.4.

Comment: I wonder why `pip -e .` isn't working: I can import my module just fine in an interpreter

Comment: @kjohnsen editable install should work - most probably the module in question is not included in the list of distributed modules. If you want, ask another question with a [mcve] and ping me in the comments here.

Comment: @hoefling Turns out this is a [VS code issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15398#issuecomment-828388565)...I tried running tests on the terminal myself and it worked fine.

Comment: I tried the pyproject.toml approach and it still doesn't see the module.

Answer (score 32):

Simply add `__init__.py` to the `tests` directory, and to all directories recursively inside it that contain test files.

Comment: But now this introduces a subtle problem: in order to load the test modules from the tests directory, pytest prepends the root of the repository to sys.path, which adds the side-effect that now mypkg is also importable. This is problematic if you are using a tool like tox to test your package in a virtual environment, because you want to test the installed version of your package, not the local code from the repository.

Comment: thats only a problem if testing the installed version matters to you. If you aren't doing anything weird with packaging it won't make a difference most of the time.

Comment: I was worried why `pytest` is not working and `python -m pytest` is working. Thanks.

Comment: @KiranKumarKotari Thank you! This resolved an issue I was having inside a docker.

Comment: python -m does the imports for you and then runs the file as a script, so it resolves relative imports

Comment: This is not recommended by pytest: https://docs.pytest.org/en/reorganize-docs/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules