# ImportError - tests failing on CircleCI but pass locally

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, circleci

Exactly as title says - my folder structure is something like this:

```
venv/  
__init__.py  
.circleci/  
    config.yml  
Dockerfile   
docker-compose.yml  
config.py  
requirements.txt  
src/  
    __init__.py  
    other_scripts.py  
tests/  
    __init__.py  
    test_a.py  
    test_b.py
```

the test files have a `from config import *` line. Running `$ pytest` from the root directory locally or through a bash shell into the container (inside a virtualenv) works as expected, but on CircleCI the build fails with an `ImportError: No module named 'config'` for the above line of code. I'm using python3.5 and circleCI 2.0.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove `__init__.py` from the root dir, add an empty file named `conftest.py`.

Comment: @hoefling that worked, thanks! It'd be great if you could add your comment and an explanation as the answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment: remove `__init__.py` from the root dir, add an empty file named `conftest.py`.

For the explanation of the `conftest.py` trick, take a look at my other answers to similar questions, for example [pytest cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028611/pytest-cannot-find-module/49033954#49033954) or [Using pytest with a src layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155464/using-pytest-with-a-src-layer/50156706#50156706). In short, adding a `conftest.py` will add the project dir to `sys.path`, so the `config` module becomes importable.

As for removal of `__init__.py` file, it's not related to the error, it just doesn't belong there. Surely, you don't want to make the project dir to a package, so an early removal of unneeded init module will spare you some unexpected errors in the future.

Comment: is this only valid for pytest or also unittest modules? I'm also getting `Failed to import test module`