# pytest-django cannot find my existing module

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pytest, pytest-django

to give a bit of context, I'm learning test unit in django and made an overly simple app to get started ([Here is the structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar41h.png)).

Here is my problem:
When launching my unit tests on my django app, I get a ModuleNotFoundError event though the module exists.

Sample of code:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .models import Book


def book_infos(request, pk):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=pk)
    return render(request, "book_infos.html", {'book': book})
```

And the test associated:

```
import pytest
from django.urls import reverse
from django.test import Client
from django_pytest.library.models import Book
from pytest_django.asserts import assertTemplateUsed


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_book_infos_view():
    client = Client()
    Book.objects.create(author="Jules Verne",
                        title="20 milles lieues sous les mers")
    path = reverse('infos', kwargs={'pk': 1})
    response = client.get(path)
    content = response.content.decode()
    expected_content = "<p>Jules Verne | 20 milles lieues sous les mers</p>"

    assert content == expected_content
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assertTemplateUsed(response, "book_infos.html")
```

My pytest.ini is as follow

```
[pytest]
pythonpath = . library tests
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = django_pytest.settings
python_files = test_*.py
```

When I run `pytest tests/library/test_views.py` from django-pytest I get this result:

```
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.5, pytest-7.4.3, pluggy-1.3.0                                                     
django: version: 4.2.7, settings: django_pytest.settings (from ini)                                             
rootdir: ...\django-pytest\django_pytest
configfile: pytest.ini                                                                                          
plugins: django-4.6.0

_ ERROR collecting tests/library/test_views.py _

ImportError while importing test module '...\django-pytest\django_pytest\tests\library\test_views.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_pytest.tests'
```

The same test run in debug I get this:

```
ERROR: not found: ...\django-pytest\django_pytest\tests\library\test_views.py::test_book_infos_view
(no name '...\\django-pytest\\django_pytest\\tests\\library\\test_views.py::test_book_infos_view' in any of [<Module test_views.py>])

tests/library/test_views.py:None (tests/library/test_views.py)
ImportError while importing test module '...\django-pytest\django_pytest\tests\library\test_views.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
..\..\..\venv\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py:617: in _importtestmodule
    mod = import_path(self.path, mode=importmode, root=self.config.rootpath)
..\..\..\venv\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\pathlib.py:567: in import_path
    importlib.import_module(module_name)
C:\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_pytest.tests'
```

What I tried:
I checked the pytest/pytest-django compatibility.
I added `pythonpath = . library tests` to the pytest.ini [following this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028611/pytest-cannot-find-module).
I tried launching `py -m pytest` from `django-pytest` instead of `django-pytest/django_pytest` but got the following `ERROR django_pytest/tests/library/test_views.py - django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessin...`
I tried changing project structure (moving test in library module).

Would anyone have an idea why this error shows ?

Thank you!

Stack :

```
Python==3.11
Django==4.2.7
pytest==7.4.3
pytest-django==4.6.0
```

(All packages installed in venv)

Comment: Looks like the rootdir is wrong: `rootdir: ...\django-pytest\django_pytest` . The pythonpath config variable is relative to rootdir ([docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference/reference.html#confval-pythonpath)), so pytest is looking for python modules in `django_pytest` instead of the project root directory. Have you tried removing the pythonpath config variable from pytest.ini?

Comment: These could be useful to you: [determining rootdir and configfile](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference/customize.html#initialization-determining-rootdir-and-configfile), [pytest import mechanisms and sys.path](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/explanation/pythonpath.html), [pytest-django: managing the Python path](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managing_python_path.html)

Comment: Hello @CoffeeBasedLifeform, yeah i tried without the pythonpath in pytest.ini but got the exact same results. Thanks for the links I'll look into it.

Comment: You are probably missing `__init__.py` file in your `django_pytest/` folder

Comment: Hello @SardorbekImomaliev, django_pytest/__init__.py exists (I edited the psot with the project structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to make it work :

- I changed the project structure from

```
django-pytest
\_ django_pytest
  \_ django_pytest
  |_ library
  |_ tests
  |_ __init__.py
  |_ manage.py
```

to

```
django-pytest
\_ project_tets
  \_ django_pytest
  |_ library
  |_ tests
  |_ __init__.py
  |_ manage.py
```

- I changed the imports in my tests from

```
from project_test.library.models import Book
```

to

```
from library.models import Book
```

These modifications don't seem much to me and I don't understand why they solved my problem.

Django create the structure of 2 packages with the same name, so I guess I'll have to systematicaly rename the parent one for pytest-django to work.

And bear with these linted import X)